# How to parse packets in a python library?

Tags: python, tcp, pcap

How to you parse a packet from either a .pcap file, or an interface, using python?

I'm specifically looking for a solution that uses a well documented library.

Comment: Hi PSS, so how you completed your project? which approached you followed?

Comment: why close this when it can clearly be edited?

Comment: For a more updated answer:
Try Kaitai Struct http://kaitai.io/ an emerging powerful, fast binary parser.
https://pythonistac.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/python-network-packet-dissection-frameworks-shootout-scapy-vs-construct-vs-hachoir-vs-kaitai-struct/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try [scapy](https://scapy.net/). It is a very powerful program for packet inspection, manipulation and creation.

You can use it to [build your own tools](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html).

Comment: See new version of scapy at http://github.com/phaethon/scapy. It is compatible with python3 and includes new functionality.

Comment: Be aware here that scapy, unusually for python libraries, is GPLv2 - note not library exemptions so typing import scapy forces your code to be GPLv2 - If you're fine with this, go for it.

Answer (score 17):

I tried that and then tried pcapy. I choose pcapy because my use was similar to an example which I found googling.

http://snipplr.com/view/3579/live-packet-capture-in-python-with-pcapy/ (or see the same code copied below)

```
import pcapy
from impacket.ImpactDecoder import *

# list all the network devices
pcapy.findalldevs()

max_bytes = 1024
promiscuous = False
read_timeout = 100 # in milliseconds
pc = pcapy.open_live("name of network device to capture from", max_bytes, 
    promiscuous, read_timeout)

pc.setfilter('tcp')

# callback for received packets
def recv_pkts(hdr, data):
    packet = EthDecoder().decode(data)
    print packet

packet_limit = -1 # infinite
pc.loop(packet_limit, recv_pkts) # capture packets
```

Answer (score 10):

I recommend you to use Pyshark. this is wrapper for tshark. it also support all of tshark filter, decoder lib, ... and easy to use!
This is a great package for parsing .pcap file and also livecapturing

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshark

sample code (from the link):

```
import pyshark
cap = pyshark.FileCapture('/root/log.cap')
cap
>>> <FileCapture /root/log.cap>
print cap[0]
Packet (Length: 698)
Layer ETH:
        Destination: BLANKED
        Source: BLANKED
        Type: IP (0x0800)
Layer IP:
        Version: 4
        Header Length: 20 bytes
        Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        Total Length: 684s
        Identification: 0x254f (9551)
        Flags: 0x00
        Fragment offset: 0
        Time to live: 1
        Protocol: UDP (17)
        Header checksum: 0xe148 [correct]
        Source: BLANKED
        Destination: BLANKED
  ...
dir(cap[0])
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_packet_string', 'bssgp', 'captured_length', 'eth', 'frame_info', 'gprs-ns', 'highest_layer', 'interface_captured', 'ip', 'layers', 'length', 'number', 'pretty_print', 'sniff_time', 'sniff_timestamp', 'transport_layer', 'udp']
cap[0].layers
[<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <UDP Layer>, <GPRS-NS Layer>, <BSSGP Layer>]
....
```

Comment: Hello, Would you please give more information on how to use pyshark to extract flow-level data from .pcap files? I have been playing with it for a while now, and as much as I know, pyshark only facilitates processing data at packet level.

Answer (score 5):

`pycapfile` can be also used. Link to `pip`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcapfile