# Capture packet content using network analyzers

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, traffic, network-traffic, web-traffic

I need to capture https traffic. In particular the client hello messages. But I need to analyse their content. I learned about wireshark. How can I to extract the data from the packet content? i.e. the client hellp content? The tool displays the packets. If I click on them, I see more information but how to aggregate them. i.e. I need the field `length` (as shown in the picture) for all `client hello` messages? 
Are there any tools to do so? Or can Wireshark do this function?

EDIT: In the picture, this is a client hello message. I need some data like the length. How to extract this and aggregate it for large traffic?
[Image for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXF9a.png)

Comment: Have you reassembled the stream?

Comment: @David Hoelzer Sorry can you clarify more what do you mean by this?

Comment: Have you right clicked on one of the packets in the TLS conversation and selected "Follow TCP Stream"?

Comment: Yes. I viewed them as ASCII. but they are not understandable (seems like encrypted data but this is strange as the client hello is sent in celar text).

Comment: It is in clear text.  Export the reassembled stream as Raw.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with wireshark with a filter of "ssl.handshake.type == 1". This will give you all Client Hello packets. From there you can manually inspect the client hello message or you can even make any field in the client hello message a column in Wireshark. To do this, drill-down into one of the packets to the field you want to see. Right-click that field and select "Apply as Column".

If you want to do this programmatically, you could also write a program that uses libpcap to capture packets. This is more work though since you would have to manually dissect the packets yourself.

Comment: But the GUI is not suitable for me. I have very large pcpa file. Aren't there any ways to process the pcpa file programmatically to pull the paramters of interest in a file?

Comment: What programming language? Python has a bunch of ways to parse packets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948043/pcap-python-library

Comment: Java and python are preferred but any programming is ok as long as it is easy to use and does the purpose.