# Extracting packet header using Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and stackoverflow, very new.

I want to extract the destination port:

```
2629  >  0 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=512 Len=100
0  >  2629 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
0  >  2633 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

I want to retrieve destination ports for every line: '0' , '2629', '2633' using python regex and ignore the rest (the number that appears after '>' and before '['.

```
re.findall("\d\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d|\d\d|\d", str)
```

but this is very generic one. What is the best regex for such scenario?

Comment: You're trying to parse the output of some program. Why not do the packet capture in Python directly? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948043/how-to-parse-packets-in-a-python-library

Comment: if you have string then split it using space and get third element `line.split(' ')[2]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the split function on string for this specific case.
A quick implementation would be:

```
dest_ports = []
lines = [
    "2629  >  0 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=512 Len=100", 
    "0  >  2629 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0", 
    "0  >  2633 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0"
]

for line in lines:
  dest_ports.append(line.split('>  ')[1].split(' [')[0])
```

Which would yield the answer:

```
dest_ports = ['0', '2629', 2633']
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a regex like this:

```
dff=io.StringIO("""2629  >  0 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=512 Len=100  
0  >  2629 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0  
0  >  2622  [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0  
0  >  2633 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0""") 

dff.seek(0) 
for line in dff: 
     print(re.search('(^\d+\s+\>\s+)(\d+)', line).groups()[1])
```